# How do you find relationship between Stack push(X) and pop() operation?

Tags: stack

I've been struggling with the the very first question of the exercise from opendatatructures.org regarding datastructures. I question goes like:

> A Dyck word is a sequence of +1's and -1's with the property that the
>   sum of any prefix of the sequence is never negative. For example,
>   +1,−1,+1,−1 is a Dyck word, but +1,−1,−1,+1 is not a Dyck word since the prefix +1 − 1 − 1 < 0. Describe any relationship between Dyck
>   words and Stack push(x) and pop() operations.

How does one find the relation between the operation?

Comment: `push` adds one item to an array. `pop` removes one item from an array. What happens if you try to remove an item from an empty array? What rules would a sequence of `push` and `pop` operations follow if you start with an empty array but made sure that you never `pop`ed that array while empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to represent check if a word if a Dyck word or not is to use a stack, where you push every time you encounter a `+1` and pop every time you encounter a `-1`. If you ever try to pop from an empty stack, it's not a Dyck word.

Consider the following psuedocode (assume that a word is represented as a array of integers, since the question isn't really about parsing):

```java
boolean isDyck(int[] word) {
    Object dummy = new Object(); // Just so you have something to push
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    for (item : word) {
        if (item > 0) {
            stack.push(dummy);
        } else {
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            stack.pop();
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```